# Python solcx incude path

Tags: solidity, py-solc-x

I am using solidity compiler version 0.8.17 via solcx wrapper.

I have some imports which are in the format `@organisation/contract/interface/c.sol`. These packages are installed via npm. The solcx compiler does not seem to have the option to include-path provided in documentation [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/path-resolution.html#base-path-and-include-paths).

The solcx documentation is located [here](https://solcx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-the-compiler.html) and i can only see options for allow path.

Is there away to provide this option to the python wrapper?

Thanks.